# Reversing a list in-place with slicing

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

Can someone please help me understand why `s[:]=s[::-1]` works perfectly but `s[]=s[::-1]` does not?

Also, would this be considered an in-place operation (without extra memory)?

Comment: What would you expect `s[]=...` to do…?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `s[]` is invalid syntax in Python.

By contrast, `s[:]` is the notation for a slice that encompasses the whole list. You could also write `s = s[::-1]`. The difference is that this changes the object that the name `s` refers to, whereas `s[:] = …` changes the *contents* of the list (and hence is in-place).

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
id(s)
# 4401507776

s[:] = s[::-1]
id(s)
# 4401507776

s = s[::-1]
id(s)
# 4434730272
```

([`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) gives you the “identity” of an object. Identical objects have the same ID, different objects have different IDs.)